# Receipt validation in iOS returns incorrect info during sandbox testing

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing receipt validation for my app, because it was paid and will be free with in app purchases going forward.

I have setup my server and everything, and I have sent the receipt data. However, when I get the response, no matter what, the response JSON always says that the `original_application_version` was `1.0`. The idea behind me validating receipts is that if your original application version was before 1.x, then you can automatically unlock the premium version.

However, even for brand new beta testers, who have never before installed the app, the `original_application_version` in the JSON is returning a value of 1.0.

the URL on my server is `https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt`. When I changed it to the production URL, I got a response of 21007 (which means I should change to the test environment).

Has anyone experienced this? I highly doubt it's going to just magically start returning the correct values in production, yet it's completely broken for testing purposes. It is returning the incorrect info on both TestFlight builds and when building directly from Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting in the sandbox environment is consistent as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW_9):

> **Original Application Version**
>
> The version of the app that was originally purchased.
>
> This corresponds to the value of **CFBundleVersion** (in iOS) or
>   CFBundleShortVersionString (in macOS) in the Info.plist file when the
>   purchase was originally made.
>
> In the sandbox environment, the value of this field is always “1.0”.
>
> <sub>Ref: [Receipt Fields: Original Application Version](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW_9)</sub>

In sandbox environment, the value of this field is always `1.0` whereas in the production environment, it will be the `CFBundleVersion` of when the user first installed this app.

Based on this, most people use the following solution:

- They change `CFBundleVersion` aka `Build` (not `Version`) to a new style
- Check this value to differentiate between the old paid app and the newer free app (with iAP)

---

[WWDC2013 Session 308: Using Receipts to Protect Your Digital Sales](https://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/308#t=602.326) spoke about this exact scenario, so what you're doing is recommended by Apple anyways.

Excerpt:

> So for everyone that's got a paid app on the store today, and you want
>   to make the transition to being a free app with In-App Purchases,
>   previously that used to be quite a challenge for you, because if you
>   simply switch to being a free app with In-App Purchases, your
>   customers would have to go and buy all those In-App Purchases again,
>   but they've already paid for it, and they're not going to like that.
>
> So now in the receipt itself we have the date, when the user first
>   purchased your app, and the version that it was at that time.
>
> So you can use this to make a really informed, intelligent decision
>   about what features and content to grant this user into, so if your
>   app looks at the receipt and inspects it and sees this user bought my
>   app before I made the switch to being free with In-App Purchases,
>   grant them into what they've paid for, but if they purchased your app
>   after you've made the transition to being free with In-App Purchases,
>   you know then not too unlock features and content until they make the
>   purchase and you verify that transaction with the receipt itself.
>
> <sub>Ref: [Using Receipts to Protect Your Digital Sales](https://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/308#t=602.326)</sub>

---

#### Summary:

But you already seem to be following this approach.
The only thing is that in sandbox environment, it's always `1.0` because every install is treated as a fresh install, no carry-forward information.
So you can't really test it until it goes to production, which is scary.

#### Viable Solution:

So how would one test the following scenarios?

1. User installed app when it was paid
2. User installed app after it became free

Hm... I would use `environment` alongwith `original_application_version`... and 2 TestFlight builds:

**Case 1: User installs app after it became free but has paid for it previously**

- If `environment` shows `Sandbox` then I would mock the `original_application_version` to an old app build number and check the flow
- Else `environment` shows `Production` and I would take the `original_application_version` from the receipt
- Provide TestFlight build with release notes indicating the case

**Case 2: User installs app after it became free but has not paid for it**

- If `environment` shows `Sandbox` then I would mock the `original_application_version` to new app build number and check the flow
- Else `environment` shows `Production` and I would take the `original_application_version` from the receipt
- Provide TestFlight build with release notes indicating the case

In either case I would get the proper receipt ofcourse, and note that both TestFlight builds are releasable if QA passes it, as long as our `else` condition is guaranteed to work: The part which takes the `original_application_version` from the receipt.

---

PS: The solution was the best I could think of right now

Comment: thanks for your time. I finally found a solution and posted what I did as an  answer here.

Comment: @joey I am not sure if only `original_purchase_date` is a good idea. Check [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37581224/2857130). However, as per this [blog](https://www.andr.mu/logs/migrating-an-ios-app-from-paid-to-freemium/), the guy used both `original_application_version` and `original_purchase_date`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally have this sorted out. As others have previously stated in other stack overflow threads, `original_application_version` is completely useless. In sandbox, it always returns `1.0`. In production, it doesn't return the version number, but rather the *build* number of your app--so the naming is bad too.

In the end, my solution (probably a very bad one, but the most straight forward ones and it does work) was to use `original_purchase_date_ms`. So from my server, I load the date (a Unix timestamp in milliseconds) that my app officially went live as free and not paid. So I just compare this number to the `original_purchase_date_ms`, and if the original purchase date was before, then it validates as them already having bought the app.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a SandBox issue.

How about capture the production replies and verify if the wrong AppVersion is there as well. (Assuming you have a 1.1+ already in store) This would be a BugReport if so, but I doubt it that the field is incorrect.

However if the field is incorrect there as well, how about validating the purchase date which was correct last time I was testing.

Comment: right now this version of the app isn't in production, so I can't receive those. after some more digging, I see that the value of original_purchase_date is always 1.0 in sandbox mode: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html. I tried original_purchase_date as well, but that returned a value of August 1, 2013. My app went on sale initially in March 2019, so obviously that is incorrect as well.