# Receipt validation. returning incorrect original_puchase_date during sandbox testing

Tags: ios

I posted a similar question here regarding receipt validation returning the incorrect original_application_version: [Receipt validation in iOS returns incorrect info during sandbox testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005918/receipt-validation-in-ios-returns-incorrect-info-during-sandbox-testing)

Since then I have been trying to use the `original_purchase_date_ms` property from the receipt validation json but it always returns the value `1375340400000`, which is some time in August of 2013. My app didn't go on sale until March 2019, so I know this info is wrong. It has returned this value for both me and on TestFlight for other users.

So is there any way to actually validate the receipt of an iOS app? I've seen plenty of tutorials but once I actually get down to it, it seems like everything is consistently returning the incorrect values, and I don't have confidence that it's going to suddenly start working correctly in production.

Edit, here is the whole verify receipt JSON I'm getting back:

```
{
"environment" : "Sandbox",
"receipt" : {
"request_date_ms" : "1557395631918",
"original_purchase_date_ms" : "1375340400000",
"in_app" : [

],
"receipt_creation_date" : "2019-05-09 09:53:49 Etc\/GMT",
"application_version" : "64",
"download_id" : 0,
"request_date" : "2019-05-09 09:53:51 Etc\/GMT",
"adam_id" : 0,
"bundle_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"original_purchase_date" : "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc\/GMT",
"original_purchase_date_pst" : "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America\/Los_Angeles",
"receipt_creation_date_ms" : "1557395629000",
"request_date_pst" : "2019-05-09 02:53:51 America\/Los_Angeles",
"receipt_creation_date_pst" : "2019-05-09 02:53:49 America\/Los_Angeles",
"version_external_identifier" : 0,
"receipt_type" : "ProductionSandbox",
"app_item_id" : 0,
"original_application_version" : "1.0"
},
"status" : 0
}
```

The only correct value is the receipt creation date, which doesn't help. Nothing else is correct.

Comment: It's sandbox environment so you should be looking `original_purchase_date` rather than `original_purchase_date_ms`. But anyways, share your in-app-purchase receipt response and let us have a look

Comment: Your `in_app` array is empty. Looks like you don't have any in-app-purchases. You're supposed to look at the `original_purchase_date` within an `in_app` object

Comment: im not validating the receipt for in app purchases, but for the purchase of the app (this app is currently a paid app on the App Store. I am moving to free with in app purchases)

Comment: @staticVoidMan this method doesn't work for validating purchased apps, only in app purchases then?

Comment: its sandbox environment so the values u see are the junk defaults. Everybody gets those in sandbox, only the `in_app` ones come with somewhat proper values. But I am not entirely sure because I haven't worked on something similar. I wud recommend u to continue ur research and find some proper documentation on this scenario.